# Super User questions that can be migrated?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

[Random](https://superuser.com/users/307/random) asked us to go through [the android tag on SU](https://superuser.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bandroid%5D%20views:1000%20migrated:0) and pick out the high view count/voted question we want to migrate to here. Otherwise he is going to clear them out if they don't mention a PC connection.

If anyone would like to help look through the questions and see what would fit good here, then please do.  Post the good ones and us mods will get them flagged to be migrated here.

Comment: I wouldn't call any "good".  Most would just be dupes.

Comment: They must've had a change of heart, I went through the Android questions on SU a while ago, and flagged the best of the non-PC related ones for migration, and one of the SU mods got annoyed and told me off for it!

Comment: In my quick perusal I didn't spot any that would be good migration candidates. I do keep an eye on the "android" tag over there, so any of the decent questions have probably already been migrated.

Comment: Okay, I looked closer and flagged a few.

Comment: @Al are you sure you *want* these? Most of owners haven't been on SU for some time - you're likely to end up with abandoned questions on your site...

Comment: @DMA57361: Yep. Some are duplicates with much better answers. Some are topics I've not seen covered here. I _was_ discriminating.

Comment: @Al I'd already sent over those with accepted answers, the rest should probably appear shortly.

Comment: @DMA57461: Thanks.

Comment: @AlEverett thanks for looking into it

Comment: @al you should only want the *high quality* questions migrated. Golden rule of all migrations: don't migrate crap!

Comment: @Jeff: I hear ya. There were a _lot_ of questions I didn't flag for migration.